# Twilio Chat typing() is not working

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

i'm successfully integrate the twilio chat api on javascript, however i got problem on .typing() function, it seems the typing function is not triggering the

'typingStarted' and 'typingEnded', can i have some advice?

here is my code

```
  var chatChannel;
  var chatClient;
  var username;

  $.post("/tokens", function(data) {
    username = data.username;
    chatClient = new Twilio.Chat.Client(data.token);
    chatClient.getSubscribedChannels().then(createOrJoinGeneralChannel);
  });

  function createOrJoinGeneralChannel() {
    // Get the general chat channel, which is where all the messages are
    // sent in this simple application
    // print('Attempting to join "general" chat channel...');
    var promise = chatClient.getChannelByUniqueName("#{params[:chat_channel]}");
    promise.then(function(channel) {
        chatChannel = channel;
        console.log("#{params[:chat_channel]} is exist");
        console.log(chatChannel);
        setupChannel();
    }).catch(function() {
        // If it doesn't exist, let's create it
        console.log("creating #{params[:chat_channel]} channel");
        chatClient.createChannel({
            uniqueName: "#{params[:chat_channel]}",
            friendlyName: 'General Chat Channel'
        }).then(function(channel) {
            console.log("Created #{params[:chat_channel]} channel:");
            console.log(channel);
            chatChannel = channel;
            setupChannel();
        });
    });
  }

  function setupChannel() {
    chatChannel.join().then(function(channel) {
      printMessage(username + ' joined the chat.');
      chatChannel.on('typingStarted', showTypingStarted);
      chatChannel.on('typingEnded', hideTypingStarted);
    });
    chatChannel.on('messageAdded', function(message) {
      printMessage(message.author + ": " + message.body);
    });
  }

  function showTypingStarted(member) {
    console.log('somebody is typing');
    $('#is_typing').html(member.identity + ' is typing...')
  }

  function hideTypingStarted(member) {
    $('#is_typing').html('');
  }

  var $input = $('#chat-input');
  $input.on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      chatChannel.sendMessage($input.val());
      $input.val('');
    } else {
      //console.log('typing');
      chatChannel.typing();
    }
  });
```

im using this version of api

https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/v1.0/twilio-chat.js

Comment: Just to confirm, are you finding the typing events aren't firing for one user when you are logged in as a different user and start typing?

Comment: yes you are right, it should be tested from the other chat users, not on our own chat window

Answer (score 3):

My Bad, the code was okay however i tried with a wrong use case, we need to test it from the other side of chat user, not on our own chat window

cheers

Comment: Thank you for posting this. This is exactly what my issue was as well. I spent a couple hours troubleshooting only to realize that I needed to be testing a separate account. Twilio won't show me when I'm typing. Only when someone else is.